# Why is my code not rendering the interface or working at all?

Tags: kotlin

After adding a while loop with the condition true (for an infinite loop), the interface (buttons) is not even drawn at startup in the emulator. What could this be related to? How can this be fixed? This is the first time I'm making an app (for my smart home API)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var webview: WebView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        webview = findViewById(R.id.browser)

        MyThread().start()
    }

    inner class MyThread : Thread() {
        override fun start() {
            super.start()
            while (true) {
                runOnUiThread {
                    updateWebView()
                }
                sleep(60000L)
            }
        }
    }
    private fun updateWebView() {
        webview.loadUrl("https://api.site.com/?action=status&device_osversion=${Build.VERSION.SDK_INT}&device_release=${Build.VERSION.RELEASE}&device_device=${Build.DEVICE}&device_model=${Build.MODEL}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new thread in Kotlin/Java, you should not override `start()`, but `run()` function. `run()` is the "body" of the thread. `start()` is used to schedule thread to start.

As a result, you didn't really run your loop inside `MyThread`. It was executed on the main thread, blocking it indefinitely.

Also, be aware that this thread will execute even after the activity has been closed. Each time you open `MainActivity` a new thread will start, leaking resources.

Comment: Well, I tried to understand how to fix my problem. So, I changed `start()` to `run()`. Now I have interface, but webview is still not working.                       `inner class MyThread : Thread() {
        override fun run() {
            super.run()`

Comment: Did you try to invoke `loadUrl()` directly from the `onCreate()` to see if it works? Maybe the problem is unrelated to the thread.